# Are the Great Question and Great Answer badges still possible?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, badges, voting

These badges feel like artifacts of the past, when posts received many more upvotes. I haven't seen any recent posts that have even come close to 100 upvotes. Am I wrong?

Comment: Give them some time?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/22/great-question) are questions that have recently received the Great Question badge and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/25/great-answer) are ones that have recently received the Great Answer badge.

Comment: The top post on the page you linked is 5 years old, and the next is 10 years old. All of those posts are from a time when posts received many more upvotes.

Comment: @alec_a you expect an answer given 2 days ago to get 100 upvotes? this would be suspicious

Comment: @alec_a Yes, because it generally *takes a long time* to accumulate that many votes. That doesn't make them obsolete. Voting doesn't stop on posts after some predetermined amount of time.

Comment: @alec_a And despite them being years old, you'll notice they *just received* the badge today, because today is when they passed the threshold. Very, very few posts reach 100 votes in a short period of time. The vast majority of those badges are awarded based on trickle votes that come in over time from search visitors, duplicate attention, etc.

Comment: @alec_a that’s a completely unfounded assertion, easily disproven ([22 posts created in the past 6 months](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=score%3a100%20created%3a6m) have reached that point already). Good posts created today that are helpful to future visitors absolutely can reach +100 scores.

Comment: @alec_a: I have 95 such badges and I answer Python questions, almost exclusively. If your answers are not gaining votes, **it is not the voting that’s at fault**. Just because you post doesn’t mean you automatically receive votes, you actually need to create helpful and valuable content.

Comment: @TemaniAfif It's not really that suspicious.  Posts get posted to social media platforms and occasionally go viral, resulting in several dozen or, in some cases, hundreds, of votes within hours.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, their rate is maybe flattening out a bit but not falling dramatically

#### Great Answers and Great Question badges per month

[image: Great Q/A badges]

#### Up and down votes per month

[image: up and down votes]

#### Questions and Answers per month

[image: q and a]

#### Post feedback by anonymous visitors and users without the right privilege

[image: Post feedback]

---

<sup>click the image to get to the SEDE query</sup>

Comment: Could you possibly also create a query for the distribution of post age vs. count for *when* questions and answers got the great {x} badges?

Comment: I'd be convinced if you have an upvote graph that shows upvotes haven't fallen off. I suspect the time between posting and awarding is getting longer on average, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: @alec_a upvotes haven't been falling off either but I'm concerned about the down votes.

Comment: Hmm. That's surprising to me. Guess my inclinations were wrong.

Comment: @WaiHaLee unfortunately that relation isn't available: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236582/add-post-id-to-badges-table-when-applicable

Comment: Ah, yes. I was about to try to construct a query (my SQL is very basic) then saw that [the schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/284827) for the badges table doesn't reference the post. Oh well - thanks for finding that SE question though.

Comment: With a growing body of questions and answers to spend your votes on I can see that voting gets spread out a bit.

Comment: Perhaps a plot of new posts is also applicable? If post counts are flattening out at the same rate..

Comment: @MartijnPieters you and me are clearly slacking ...

Comment: If it's not a trouble, maybe include graph with anonymous feedback to indicate how many posts would get the badge if they were real votes.

Comment: @AndrewT. funny enough that has a much better distribution between up and down votes

Comment: @rene: so the rate of badges keeps pace with the rate of posts. No flattening of badge awards then.

Comment: @MartijnPieters hey, I'm only the SEDE magician ... how you want to spin these outcomes in your favor is up to you ;)

Comment: @rene: spin me this then: number of great answer and question badges as a ratio of the number of new posts! :-)

Comment: [here ya go](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1035312) ..

Answer (score 2):

> I haven't seen any recent posts that have even come close to 100 upvotes.

Based on [the search for the newest posts having score>= 100](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=score%3a100), the newest post was posted on **Apr 15** (6 days ago). However, most of them are indeed Q&A that got into Hot Network Questions, so they might not be getting upvotes "naturally".

For a more broad answer, refer to [rene's statistically backed-up answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/383087).